# HaxeDevelop - Error: Unable to access jarfile BUILD='release'

Tags: haxe

I have created a CreateJS App in HaxeDevelop and written nothing. When I press **Test Project (F5)** the output window spits out this:

[image]

When I actually write some Haxe files they don't get trans-piled to the bin folder. What am I doing wrong?